# In Swift, rounding is not occurring as expected

Tags: swift, string, formatting, rounding

Here's the line of code in question:

```
let finalNumber = String(format: "%.2f", anotherNumber)
// where anotherNumber is a decimal like 123.456789
```

The output I'm getting is 123.45. I would expect this to get rounded up to 123.46.

Can anyone tell me why it's not rounding correctly?

Comment: You should post a real example.  That one prints `123.46`.

Comment: I am getting `123.46` in a playground

Comment: It is woking as expected.So, what is you actual problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following function in playground

```
func roundToDecimal(_ fractionDigits: Int, value: Double) -> Double {
  let multiplier = pow(10, Double(fractionDigits))
  return Darwin.round(value * multiplier) / multiplier
}


roundToDecimal(2, value: 123.456789)
```

you will get your result 123.46